# To control the relay switching in nextion using esp32 Microcontroller

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, relay, dht22

I have developed the code to control the relay switching on/off using nextion display and esp32. But whenever I press my dual state button in the nextion display there is some delay and I need to press my dual state button continuously in nextion display for about 10 to 15 seconds to switch on/off the relay.

I am stuck in this work and I 'm looking for help. I need to switch on/off the relay on a single tap on the dual sate button on nextion display. Below I have attached my code,

```cpp
#include "NexDualStateButton.h"
#include "Nextion.h"
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 27
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
int R1 = 2;
uint32_t dual_state ;

NexText tTempC = NexText(0, 4, "tTempC");
NexText tHumidity = NexText(0, 6, "tHumidity");
NexDSButton bt0 = NexDSButton(0, 8, "bt0");

char buffer[100] = {0};

NexTouch *nex_listen_list[] =
{
    &bt0,
    NULL
};

void bt0PopCallback(void *ptr)
{
  uint32_t dual_state;
  NexDSButton *btn = (NexDSButton *)ptr;

  dbSerialPrintln("bt0PopCallback");
  dbSerialPrint("ptr=");

  dbSerialPrintln((uint32_t)ptr);
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

  bt0.getValue(&dual_state);

  if(dual_state>0)
  {
    digitalWrite(R1, LOW);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(R1, HIGH);
  }
}

void setup(void) {
   dht.begin();
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(R1, OUTPUT);

   nexInit();
   bt0.attachPop(bt0PopCallback, &bt0);

   Serial.println("DHT Sensor Reading");
   dbSerialPrintln("setup done");
}

void loop(void) {
  nexLoop(nex_listen_list);
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float h = dht.readHumidity();

  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
    Serial2.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }

  static char temperatureCTemp[10];
  dtostrf(t, 6, 2, temperatureCTemp);
  tTempC.setText(temperatureCTemp);

  char hTemp[10] = {0};
  utoa(int(h), hTemp, 10);
  tHumidity.setText(hTemp);

  Serial.print(F("Humidity: "));
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(F("%  Temperature: "));
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print("°C ");
  //Serial2.print(F("tTempC.txt="));

  //Serial.print("");
  //Serial.print(F("tHumidity.txt:\ "));
  //Serial.print(h);
  //Serial.write(0xff);
  //Serial.write(0xff);
  //Serial.write(0xff);
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the `NexDualStateButton` class? Is that defined by Nextion? And what is Nextion?

Comment: If I didn't include the NexDualStateButton in the include statement, I am getting an error as NexDSButton was not declared. So only I included the NexDualStateButton in the include statement

Comment: Also, I downloaded the nextion stable environment library(Nextion 7.0.0) and I added that in Arduino IDE. I can't able to add the Nextion unstable version which contains the dual state button library.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What is that class? I understand that you need it, but what does it do? You're using classes without explaining where they come from, what they are for, or where they are documented.

Comment: If I include that class my dual state button works. The Nextion library is not so stable.

Comment: You are not providing enough information for us to help you. I've voted to close your question.

Comment: Actually I am new to Arduino programming and whatever I am is like trial and error method. The Class #include "NexDualStateButton.h" is used to declare the library of NextionDualState Button.

Answer (score 1):

I think this method inefficent. Because ESP32  continuously listens to the button state.

You will try this method . Working for me .

```
int R1 = 2;
NexDSButton bt0 = NexDSButton(0, 8, "bt0");
uint32_t dual_state=0;

void setup(){
nexInit();
pinMode(R1, OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
bt0.getValue(&dual_state);

if(dual_state==1) //When pressed dual state button dual_state =1
  {
    digitalWrite(R1, HIGH);
  }
  else if(dual_state==0)
  {
    digitalWrite(R1,LOW ); 
  }

}
```

Comment: I am using for taking button state in my case. Don't use if you don't want to use it. Its wait after take button state 200ms and enter if condition . Sometimes there is a delay between arduino and nextion i am waiting because of this .

Comment: this delay not for this. in my project i am changing dual_state as 0 after if condition . This is for my case. If you dont want to use it then dont use it.

Comment: You're overreacting bye

Comment: Thanks Alper Aslan. I will check using your code and will let you know soon.

Comment: No, Juraj has a point. Don't include code that does not make sense for most users in your answer. You say "I am using for taking button state in my case." That suggests that most users would not need or want that delay, so edit your answer and delete it. The `delay()` function causes all sorts of problems, and it should only be used in very special circumstances.

Comment: Ok guys i will edit you are right thanks for your advice

Comment: @AbhishekhAaron you are welcome i am using this code on my project and working properly its not listen all time. Its just listen when pressed button and take button state.

Comment: Thanks, guys. My code works. Alper Aslan I used your code for my dual state button and it works now. Below I have attached my code,

Comment: @AbhishekhAaron what a good news :)

Comment: @AbhishekhAaron, what is the value of the dual_state variable if it is not 1?

Comment: @Juraj Sorry, I didn't get your question?

Comment: Its written on if condition its zero

Comment: I try to understand the differ3nce between the code in question and code in answer. they look equivalent.

Comment: @Juraj in question code bt0 state listen all the time by Esp32. In NexTouch nex_listen_list object.

Comment: I don't see what line is different

Comment: char buffer[100] = {0};

NexTouch *nex_listen_list[] =
{
    &bt0,
    NULL
};

Comment: ok. sorry I compared the codes in both answers not with the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated code to display the temperature and humidity in Nextion display and also to control the relay switching in Nextion display. It works good.

```cpp
#include "NexDualStateButton.h"
#include "Nextion.h"
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 27
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

int R1 = 2;
NexDSButton bt0 = NexDSButton(0, 8, "bt0");
NexText tTempC = NexText(0, 4, "tTempC");
NexText tHumidity = NexText(0, 6, "tHumidity");
uint32_t dual_state=0;

void setup(){
  dht.begin();  
  nexInit();
  pinMode(R1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  bt0.getValue(&dual_state);

  if(dual_state==1) //When pressed dual state button dual_state =1
  {
    digitalWrite(R1, HIGH);
  }
  else if(dual_state==0)
  {
    digitalWrite(R1,LOW ); 
  }
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float h = dht.readHumidity();

  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
    Serial2.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }

  static char temperatureCTemp[10];
  dtostrf(t, 6, 2, temperatureCTemp);
  tTempC.setText(temperatureCTemp);

  char hTemp[10] = {0}; 
  utoa(int(h), hTemp, 10);
  tHumidity.setText(hTemp);

  Serial.print(F("Humidity: "));
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(F("%  Temperature: "));
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print("°C ");

}
```

Comment: It's OK to accept you're own answer as the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to print the temperature to the display and call the BT button without using the Nextion Library. In this example, I am using a TCA9548A because I am using 2 BMP280s.

```
void TEMP() {
  delay(125);
  TCA9548A(0);
  HMISerial10.print("t8.txt=\"");
  HMISerial10.print((bmp.readTemperature() * 1.8) + 32);
  HMISerial10.print("\"");
  HMISerial10.write(0xff);
  HMISerial10.write(0xff);
  HMISerial10.write(0xff);
  Serial.print("Inside Temp: ");
  Serial.println((bmp.readTemperature() * 1.8) + 32);

  TCA9548A(1);
  HMISerial10.print("t7.txt=\"");
  HMISerial10.print((bmp.readTemperature() * 1.8) + 32);
  HMISerial10.print("\"");
  HMISerial10.write(0xff);
  HMISerial10.write(0xff);
  HMISerial10.write(0xff);
  Serial.print("Outside Temp: ");
  Serial.println((bmp.readTemperature() * 1.8) + 32);
}
```

Here I have it looking for a button from the Nextion

```
void dfd_listen() {


  delay(30);
  dfd = ""; //dfd means Data From Display
  while (HMISerial5.available()) { //This will look to see if there is something coming from the Nextion
    dfd += char(HMISerial5.read());
  }

  if (dfd.substring(1, 4) == "bt4" && dfd.substring(0, 1) == "0") {
    digitalWrite(R6, LOW);   // Roof Lights
    HMISerial5.write(0xff);  // We always have to send this three lines after each command sent to the nextion display.
    HMISerial5.write(0xff);
    HMISerial5.write(0xff);
    Serial.println("Roof Lights OFF");
  } else if (dfd.substring(1, 4) == "bt4" && dfd.substring(0, 1) == "1") {
    digitalWrite(R6, LOW);   // Roof Lights
    HMISerial5.write(0xff);  // We always have to send this three lines after each command sent to the nextion display.
    HMISerial5.write(0xff);
    HMISerial5.write(0xff);
    Serial.println("Roof Lights ON");
  }

  if (dfd.substring(1, 4) == "b17") {
    HMISerial5.print("page 1");
    HMISerial5.write(0xff);  // We always have to send this three lines after each command sent to the nextion display.
    HMISerial5.write(0xff);
    HMISerial5.write(0xff);
    Serial.println("Change to Page 1");
    dfd = "";
    delay(100);
  }
```

Now this shows both BT and B buttons. The HMISerial are my serial ports the Nextion are attached to. The "dfd" is set as a string before your setup.
For the Nextion button, you just have to add a value and set it as a string, in this case, my value is va11. Then on the button on the press event, you would put something like this.

```
  if(bt4.val==1)
{
  cov bt4.val,va11.txt,1
  va11.txt+="bt4"
  print va11.txt
  t4.pco=17576
}else if(bt4.val==0)
{
  cov bt4.val,va11.txt,1
  va11.txt+="bt4"
  print va11.txt
  t4.pco=57033
}
```